# Как записать информацию в файл перед последним словом?

Tags: php, файлы

Пишу функцию для генерирования `sitemap.xml`.

Как добавить определенную информацию в конец файла, перед последним словом?

В данном случае это тег `</urlset>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну если весь текст в переменной `$txt`, то проще `str_replace()` ничего быть не может.

```
$txt = str_replace('</urlset>', '[text-to-add]</urlset>', $txt);
```

Comment: Да, все проще чем я думал

Comment: Ваш вопрос очень простой. Советую его стереть. Ну или, если мой ответ подходит, - ставьте галочку :)